# Create websocket using golang in aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, https, gorilla

I am trying to create websockets using golang with gorilla on aws (without docker) with load balancer, I have a certificate connected to the load balancer.

I managed to make the code work with http, but when I try to use the code over https it does not work.

What am I doing wrong?
When moving from http to https I changed the client request to wss instead of ws, and added the certificate to the load balancer.
Here is my code.
This is my main.go

```
    http.HandleFunc("/wss", serveWs)

fmt.Printf("Listening on port %s\n\n", port)


if err := http.ListenAndServe(":"+port, nil); err != nil {
    fmt.Printf(err.Error())
}
```

This is the serveWs:

```
func serveWs(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
upgrader.CheckOrigin = func(r *http.Request) bool {
    // allow all connections by default
    return true
}

ws, err := upgrader.Upgrade(w, r, nil)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
    if _, ok := err.(websocket.HandshakeError); !ok {
        log.Println(err)
    }
    return
}

var lastMod time.Time

if n, err := strconv.ParseInt(r.FormValue("lastMod"), 16, 64); err != nil {
    lastMod = time.Unix(0, n)
}

go writer(ws, lastMod, w, r)
reader(ws)
```

}

This is the request:

```
 var conn = new WebSocket("wss://https://www.weldpad.com/wss?"
```

When I send a request from the client i get the folloing error:

failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 400

Looking at the server log, I see.

"could not find upgrade header with token 'websocket"

This is my load balancer configuration:

[Load Balancing Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T7jO9.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it should be `wss://www.weldpad.com/wss?` not `wss://https://www.weldpad.com/wss?`

Comment: I have also tried it and the responce was: wsconnect.html WebSocket connection to 'wss://www.weldpad.com/wss' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 400

Comment: Well that's a much better error message. It's getting a response from the server. Now you need to look at your server, maybe examine the server logs, and see why it is returning a 400 code.

Comment: Looking at the log, I found "websocket: could not find upgrade header with token 'websocket'", I am looking into it.

Comment: Found it, I was missing a load balancer mapping for tcp, mapping is SSL to tcp, once I enabled it, everything worked, thanks Mark, Your comment focused me on the problem.